# Setting Account sync indicator red (or other colors too)

Tags: android

I'm trying to indicate the authentication / sync status of an account using the AccountAuthenticator and SyncAdapter.  I've been through the samples, and can get it working alright.

How can I set the indicator to red just like the GMail account?

I'd also like to add additional status indicators on the sync adapter page.  See picture below:

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question for future team knowledge...

Getting the indicator to change color was fairly easy after some experimentation.  Start by creating a project based on thecode supplied in the SDK sample projects, modify as follows:

1) Fake the initial login from the server during the AuthenticationActivity.  Once past the initial check, the system will start it's periodic sync attempts.

```
/**
 * Called when the authentication process completes (see attemptLogin()).
 */
public void onAuthenticationResult(boolean result) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onAuthenticationResult(" + result + ")");
    // Hide the progress dialog
    hideProgress();
    //  Override the result, we don't care right now....
    result = true;
    if (result) {
        if (!mConfirmCredentials) {
            finishLogin();
        } else {
            finishConfirmCredentials(true);
        }
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "onAuthenticationResult: failed to authenticate");
        if (mRequestNewAccount) {
            // "Please enter a valid username/password.
            mMessage.setText(getText(R.string.login_activity_loginfail_text_both));
        } else {
            // "Please enter a valid password." (Used when the
            // account is already in the database but the password
            // doesn't work.)
            mMessage.setText(getText(R.string.login_activity_loginfail_text_pwonly));
        }
    }
}
```

2)  Modify the "onPerformSync()" method within the SyncAdapter.  The key here are the "syncResult.stats" fields.  While modifying them, I found that inserting multiple errors didn't get the effect I wanted.  Also noting that the counts didn't seem to be recorded across sync attempts (i.e. the fails always come in as zero).  The "lifetimeSyncs" is a static variable that keeps count across sync attempts.  This modified code will continue to alternate between green and red...

```
 @Override
public void onPerformSync(Account account, Bundle extras, String authority, ContentProviderClient provider, SyncResult syncResult) {
    List<User> users;
    List<Status> statuses;
    String authtoken = null;

    try {
        // use the account manager to request the credentials
        authtoken = mAccountManager.blockingGetAuthToken(account, Constants.AUTHTOKEN_TYPE, true );
        // fetch updates from the sample service over the cloud
        //users = NetworkUtilities.fetchFriendUpdates(account, authtoken, mLastUpdated);
        // update the last synced date.
        mLastUpdated = new Date();
        // update platform contacts.
        Log.d(TAG, "Calling contactManager's sync contacts");
        //ContactManager.syncContacts(mContext, account.name, users);
        // fetch and update status messages for all the synced users.
        //statuses = NetworkUtilities.fetchFriendStatuses(account, authtoken);
        //ContactManager.insertStatuses(mContext, account.name, statuses);

        if (SyncAdapter.lifetimeSyncs-- <= 0 ){
            //mAccountManager.invalidateAuthToken(Constants.ACCOUNT_TYPE, authtoken);
            syncResult.stats.numAuthExceptions++;
            //syncResult.delayUntil = 60;
            lifetimeSyncs = 5;
        }


    } catch (final AuthenticatorException e) {
        syncResult.stats.numParseExceptions++;
        Log.e(TAG, "AuthenticatorException", e);
    } catch (final OperationCanceledException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "OperationCanceledExcetpion", e);
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "IOException", e);
        Log.d(TAG, extras.toString());
        syncResult.stats.numAuthExceptions++;
        syncResult.delayUntil = 60;
        //extras.putString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTH_FAILED_MESSAGE, "You're not registered");
    } catch (final ParseException e) {
        syncResult.stats.numParseExceptions++;
        Log.e(TAG, "ParseException", e);
    }

}
```

That's it, enjoy playing with the delays and other variables too...